# Why Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) are different from Self-Executing Anonymus Functions?

Tags: javascript, iife

It is clear that in EcmaScript, functions when invoked create a new execution context. All variables and functions defined within a function may only be accessed inside that function scope. But when we use closures variables and functions may be accessed outside that context. 
IIFE is a function expression that gets invoked immediately. It is simple.

But why are IIFE different from Self-Executing Anonymus Functions, it is not completely clear to me!?

Comment: Relevant article: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Related to self executing anonymous functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108429/immediately-invoke-a-function-declaration-without-using-iife-pattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the same, it was renamed to `IIFE` because an `IIFE` is not necessarily anonymous, and they do not execute themselves.

consider the following:

```
(function bleh() {
    alert('I am not anonymous, i have a name!');
})(); //<-- invoked like any other function
```

Comment: *renamed* might not be the right term, there are many names for the same concept – "Immediate functions", "self-executing functions", etc

Comment: I have found an excellent explanation given by Mark Dalgleish here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=KRm-h6vcpxs#t=699s



– 1) IIFE do not execute them selves, they are invoked like any other function


– 2) IIFE do not have to be anonimous, it is only important that they are function expressions.

Comment: Mea culpa -- my distraction